# I am unable to send email to recipient with Field Locators

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am not able to send email(s), I've tried with my real email and I haven't received any emails. How do I get this to work? I am not getting any errors.

Doesn't Docusign have a clean working java example on how to send a PDF file with Field Locator(s) to be signed by recipient.  I got this sample code from Docusign:

```
        // Enter your DocuSign credentials
        String UserName = "myUserName@hotmail.com";
        String Password = "MyPassword";    
        String IntegratorKey = "c8ad614b-def7-4631-aede-c90e68ef84d4";

        // specify a document we want signed
        String SignTest1File = "C:/Users/Public/test/TEST.PDF";

        // enter recipient (signer) name and email
        String recipientName = "Recipient Name";
        String recipientEmail = "RecipientEmail@yahoo.com";     

        // for production environment update to "www.docusign.net/restapi"
        String BaseUrl = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";

        // initialize the api client for the desired environment
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
        apiClient.setBasePath(BaseUrl);

        // create JSON formatted auth header
        String creds = "{\"Username\":\"" +  UserName + "\",\"Password\":\"" +  Password + "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" +  IntegratorKey + "\"}";
        apiClient.addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", creds);

        // assign api client to the Configuration object
        Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(apiClient);

        // create an empty list that we will populate with accounts
        List<LoginAccount> loginAccounts = null;

        try
        {
            // login call available off the AuthenticationApi
            AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();

            // login has some optional parameters we can set
            AuthenticationApi.LoginOptions loginOps = authApi.new LoginOptions();
            loginOps.setApiPassword("true");
            loginOps.setIncludeAccountIdGuid("true");
            LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.login(loginOps);

            // note that a given user may be a member of multiple accounts
            loginAccounts = loginInfo.getLoginAccounts();

            System.out.println("LoginInformation: " + loginAccounts);
        }
        catch (com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
        }

        // create a byte array that will hold our document bytes
        byte[] fileBytes = null;

        try
        {
            //String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            // read file from a local directory
            //Path path = Paths.get(currentDir + SignTest1File);
            Path path = Paths.get(SignTest1File);
            fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        }
        catch (IOException ioExcp)
        {
            // handle error
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ioExcp);
            return;
        }

        // create an envelope that will store the document(s), tabs(s), and recipient(s)
        EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        envDef.setEmailSubject("[Java SDK] - Please sign this doc");

        // add a document to the envelope
        Document doc = new Document();  
        String base64Doc = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileBytes);
        doc.setDocumentBase64(base64Doc);
        doc.setName("TestFile.pdf");    // can be different from actual file name
        doc.setDocumentId("1");

        List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<Document>();
        docs.add(doc);
        envDef.setDocuments(docs);

        // add a recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email we used above
        Signer signer = new Signer();
        signer.setName(recipientName);  
        signer.setEmail(recipientEmail);
        signer.setRecipientId("1");

        // to embed the recipient you must set their |clientUserId| property!
        signer.setClientUserId("1234");

        // create a signHere tab somewhere on the document for the signer to sign
        // default unit of measurement is pixels, can be mms, cms, inches also
        SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
        signHere.setDocumentId("1");
        signHere.setPageNumber("1");
        signHere.setRecipientId("1");
        signHere.setXPosition("100");
        signHere.setYPosition("150");

        // can have multiple tabs, so need to add to envelope as a single element list
        List<SignHere> signHereTabs = new ArrayList<SignHere>();      
        signHereTabs.add(signHere);
        Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
        tabs.setSignHereTabs(signHereTabs);
        signer.setTabs(tabs);

        // add recipients (in this case a single signer) to the envelope
        envDef.setRecipients(new Recipients());
        envDef.getRecipients().setSigners(new ArrayList<Signer>());
        envDef.getRecipients().getSigners().add(signer);

        // send the envelope by setting |status| to "sent". To save as a draft set to "created"
        envDef.setStatus("sent");

        // accountId is needed to create the envelope and for requesting the signer view
        String accountId = null;
        String envelopeId = null;

        try
        {
            // use the |accountId| we retrieved through the Login API to create the Envelope
            accountId = loginAccounts.get(0).getAccountId();

            // instantiate a new EnvelopesApi object
            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

            // call the createEnvelope() API to send the signature request!
            EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, envDef);

            // save the |envelopeId| that was generated and use in next API call
            envelopeId = envelopeSummary.getEnvelopeId();

            System.out.println("EnvelopeSummary: " + envelopeSummary);
        }
        catch (com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
        }

        // use the |accountId| we retrieved through the Login API and the |envelopeId| that was generated during envelope creation
        accountId = loginAccounts.get(0).getAccountId();

        // instantiate a new EnvelopesApi object
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

        // set the url where you want the recipient to go once they are done signing
        RecipientViewRequest returnUrl = new RecipientViewRequest();
        returnUrl.setReturnUrl("https://www.docusign.com/devcenter");
        returnUrl.setAuthenticationMethod("email");

        // recipient information must match embedded recipient info we provided in step #2
        returnUrl.setUserName(recipientName);
        returnUrl.setEmail(recipientEmail);
        returnUrl.setRecipientId("1");
        returnUrl.setClientUserId("1234");

        try 
        {
            // call the CreateRecipientView API then navigate to the URL to start the signing session
            ViewUrl recipientView = envelopesApi.createRecipientView(accountId, envelopeId, returnUrl);

            System.out.println("ViewUrl: " + recipientView);
        }
        catch (com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
        }
```

Comment: @hmax: there is no need to edit questions to add bold formatting to key technologies - it does not make it easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting below attribute in your code, which is making this recipient an embedded signer. If you set `clientUserId` then you are telling DocuSign that treat this signer as embedded signer, and for embedded Signers DocuSign does not send any email for starting the signing ceremony. If you do not set `clientUserId` then DocuSign treats it as remote Signers and you will receive an email to start the Signing ceremony.

```
signer.setClientUserId("1234");
```

[Code Example](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/request-a-signature-via-email) shows how to request an ESignature via an Email, and check [Embedded Signing Example](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/signing-from-your-app) for embedded signing or Signing from Your App.